# Convert string to variable in PHP?

Tags: php, variables

How do I go about setting a string as a literal variable in PHP? Basically I have an array like

```
$data['setting'] = "thevalue";
```

and I want to convert that `'setting'` to `$setting` so that `$setting` becomes `"thevalue"`.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [PHP variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Your question isn't completely clear but maybe you want something like this:

```
//Takes an associative array and creates variables named after
//its keys
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $$key = $value;
}
```

Comment: This is what I took the user's question to mean as well.
@iamdadude, $$key is a "variable variable"

You can set the name of a variable to be the value of another variable with the double dollar sign syntax.

Answer (score 5):

[`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) will take the keys of an array and turn them into variables with the corresponding value in the array.

Answer (score 4):

```
${'setting'} = "thevalue";
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be evil, but there is always eval.

```
$str = "setting";
$val = "thevalue";
eval("$" . $str . " = '" . $val . "'");
```

Comment: There are *so* many ways of doing it in PHP *without* `eval()`.

Comment: Absolutely true, just one (not so great) method of doing things.